# Shell Theme Not Installing Through GNOME Tweaks

Tags: themes, gnome-tweaks

I want to install the Rounded-Rectangle-Purple theme for Ubuntu to match the wallpaper I want. However, every time I try to change the theme through GNOME Tweaks, a popup will say it successfully installed, but nothing changes and will stay in light mode, as for some reason, the wallpaper only shows up in light mode.

I tried restarting, and no change still happened.

It originally comes in a tar.gz file format; however, changing to .zip or a normal folder doesn't change anything.

Theme source: https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1428657/

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

I moved the folder to the `/usr/share/themes` directory and it worked perfectly.